# How to change color of cell in JTable and animate it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with numbers. I know how to change color of one cell or all cells. But how to change color of cell in and animate it ? 
For example, The first cell of red, there is a delay, and the second cell is painted in the same red color and so on.

I inherited class DefaultTableCellRenderer

```
    class paintCell extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        return c;
    }
}
```

And set method
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new paintCell());

Comment: You might try establishing a Swing based `Timer` to call `repaint()` on the table every NN milliseconds and then adjust the cells color each time the renderer is called.  If you cannot get it working based on that, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private JTable table;
private int index;
private void startAnimation() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            index++;
            if (index > table.getRowCount() * table.getColumnCount())
                index = 0;
            table.repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}
class PaintCell extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        int id = row * table.getRowCount() + column;
        c.setBackground(id < index ? Color.RED : null);
        return c;
    }
}
```

(SeniorJD is faster than me... But I wrote the code without his answer)

Answer (score 1):

Create the `javax.swing.Timer` object. Add the `int pointer` field in your `PaintCell` renderer class and increase it on `Timer.actionPerfomed()`. Then, in `PaintCell.getTableCellRendererComponent` method cast the `value` parameter to `int` type (as you said, you have a digits in cells) and compare it with your `pointer` field. If it `equals or less`, set cells' `background` to `red`.